# How to store references of generated objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my code I generate a grid of objects with Instantiate but I don't know how to keep reference of each of them by their coordinates (I rely on int coordinates to keep things simple). At first I looked at GameObject[,] but for that I need to know the maximum size my "map" would become and I don't have that information as it is infinite as it's generated as the player moves. Another limitation I found about GameObject[,] is that I can't store negative indexes, so I would not be able to use to store x and y values inside it.

What do you suggest me to use?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at chunking? You can have a chunk which is GameObject[,] of say 20x20 objects and load and unload the chunks as you walk around...

Answer (score 0):

How sparse will you be?

If you have a lot of gaps, then something like the following will work well:

```
public struct GameObjectCoordinate : IEquatable<GameObjectCoordinate>
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public bool Equals(GameObjectCoordinate other)
    {
        return X == other.X && Y == other.Y;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is GameObjectCoordinate && Equals((GameObjectCoordinate)obj);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        /* There's a speed advantage in something simple like
        unchecked
        {
            return (X << 16 | X >> 16) ^ Y; 
        }
        and a distribution advantage in the code here. It can be worth
        trying both, but be aware that the code commented out here is better
        at small well-spread key values, and that below at large numbers of
        values especially if many are similar, so do any testing with real
        values your application will deal with.
        */  
        unchecked
        {
            ulong c = 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF + ((ulong)X << 32) + (ulong)Y;
            ulong d = 0xE2ADBEEFDEADBEEF ^ c;
            ulong a = d += c = c << 15 | c >> -15;
            ulong b = a += d = d << 52 | d >> -52;
            c ^= b += a = a << 26 | a >> -26;
            d ^= c += b = b << 51 | b >> -51;
            a ^= d += c = c << 28 | c >> -28;
            b ^= a += d = d << 9 | d >> -9;
            c ^= b += a = a << 47 | a >> -47;
            d ^= c += b << 54 | b >> -54;
            a ^= d += c << 32 | c >> 32;
            a += d << 25 | d >> -25;
            return (int)(a >> 1);
        }
    }
    Dictionary<GameObjectCoordinate, GameObject> gameObjects = new Dictionary<GameObjectCoordinate, GameObject>();
```

If you have an object at almost every position, then storing chunks of arrays, and using code similar to the above to store the chunks would likely be better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand corrctly you have a sparse map of unknown dimensions. In that case use a tree like a k-d tree. All operations are more complex than a direct look up in a table but use way less space. It will also allow negative positions like `(-1, -3)`. [See Wikipedia for details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)